# Source of Diderot quote about tools and ideas

Tags: quote-source, french-language, denis-diderot

In the German book *Usability und UX kompakt* by Michael Richter and Markus Flückiger (Springer, 2016, page 159), I found the following quote, which the authors attribute to Denis Diderot:

> Die einen, so scheint mir, haben viele Werkzeuge und wenig Ideen; die anderen haben viele Ideen und gar keine Werkzeuge.

My translation:

> Some, it seems to me, have many tools and few ideas; (the) others have many ideas and no tools at all.

What is the exact source of this quote and what was the wording of the original version in French? The [German Wikiquote page](https://fr.wikiquote.org/wiki/Denis_Diderot) and the [French Wikiquote page](https://de.wikiquote.org/wiki/Denis_Diderot) don't seem to list the quote. A [search for `diderot outils idées "les uns" "les autres"`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=diderot+outils+id%C3%A9es+%22les+uns%22+%22les+autres%22&t=ffab&ia=web), but Diderot may have used a different word than "outils" for "tools".

Comment: Why don't you ask the authors of the book?

Comment: @kimchilover Assuming they got it from the original French source is a rather bold assumption, isn't it?

Comment: Send an email to Richter and/or  Flückiger asking where they got the quote.  They might possibly have a good source (that is, one you  can use to find a place where D actually wrote something like that) or possibly they don't.

Comment: @kimchilover There are countless collections of quotes that don't mention the quote's original source. For example, [GuteZitate.com](https://gutezitate.com/zitate/interesse/16) lists that quote without mentioning its source. Authors often use that sort of source.

Comment: Yes, and so what?  Find out if R and F was in that class or not.  Punish them, at least, with the search for truth.

Answer (score 5):

After some more research, I found out that "outils" was a red herring; Diderot used the word "instruments" in the original quote. Its source is [*Pensées sur l'interprétation de la Nature*](http://sami.is.free.fr/Oeuvres/diderot_nature.html), which Diderot first published anonymously in 1753 and edited for republication in 1754 (see the [French Wikipedia article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pens%C3%A9es_sur_l%27interpr%C3%A9tation_de_la_nature)).

Here is the original version:

> Ce seront ou des vues générales sur l'art expérimental, ou des vues particulières sur un phénomène qui paraît occuper tous nos philosophes, et les diviser en deux classes. **Les uns ont, ce me semble, beaucoup d'instruments et peu d'idées; les autres ont beaucoup d'idées et n'ont point d'instruments.**

My translation:

> These will be either general views on (the art of) experimentation, or specific views about a phenomenon that appears to keep all of our philosophers occupied and divide them into two categories. **Some, it seems to me, have many instruments/tools and few ideas; the others have many ideas and no instruments/tools at all.**